# Require sudo to delete files, but still allow writing

Tags: permissions

I've got all my files on a server raid, and it has a reasonably excessive amount of space so I'm not often going to have to delete anything.

I still have things writing to the raid all the time so I don't want to have to use sudo to do that. But is it possible to set permissions so that writing is allowed but deleting files is not?

I assume this will also require me to use sudo for mv commands, but that isn't a problem

### Extra info:

Raid uses btrfs raid1

OS is on a separate drive (Ubuntu 14.04 server)

Comment: As [kvbx says](http://askubuntu.com/a/533700/22949), you can do this ...but is this really what you want to do? Someone who can write to a file can replace its contents with whatever they like. That's often just as bad as deleting the file, and sometimes more problematic.

Comment: It's more to protect from my own stupidity than for external threats

Comment: Make sure you keep good backups!  btrfs is still not considered totally production level item.

Comment: I know, I'm right this minute setting up my backup server. I almost deleted something important while preparing the transfer so thought I would check here if there was a way around accidental deletions

Answer (score 1):

You need directory write permissions to create or delete files.
You need file write permissions to change the file.

Considering this tree:

```
FolderA: (no write permissions for you)
   - FileX (write permissions)
   - FileY (write permissions)
```

You can now change FileX and FileY but you can't delete them. Nor can you create a FileZ in FolderA.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. File creation and deletion in Unix are controlled by the ability to write to the directory --- basically the same flag.

Now what you can do is create two directories --- one with write permission and the other one restricted to root.

```
[romano:~/tmp/test] % ls -l
total 8
drwxrwxr-x 2 romano romano 4096 Oct  8 18:06 normal
drwxrwxr-x 2 root   root   4096 Oct  8 18:06 onlyroot
```

You normally work on `normal`. Suppose you have in it:

```
[romano:~/tmp/test/normal] % ls
one.txt  three.txt  two.txt
```

You can clearly delete files and create new ones; suppose you want to protect "`one.txt`" from deleting. What you can do is creating a hard link to it in `onlyroot`:

```
[romano:~/tmp/test/normal] 1 % sudo ln one.txt ../onlyroot
```

This will create another name for `one.txt` in `onlyroot` (using a negligible amount of space; the file is not copied). Now as a normal user you can delete `one.txt` in the `normal` folder, but you will have an untouchable version under the `onlyroot` one.

```
[romano:~/tmp/test/normal] % ls
one.txt  three.txt  two.txt
[romano:~/tmp/test/normal] % rm one.txt
rm: remove regular empty file ‘one.txt’? y
[romano:~/tmp/test/normal] % cd ..
[romano:~/tmp/test] % cd onlyroot 
[romano:~/tmp/test/onlyroot] % ls
one.txt
[romano:~/tmp/test/onlyroot] % rm one.txt 
rm: remove regular empty file ‘one.txt’? y
rm: cannot remove ‘one.txt’: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding (based on https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Project_ideas#RichACLs_.2F_NFS4_ACLS), btrfs supports only traditional Unix permissions and POSIX.1e ACLs, and hence can't do what you want.

Many/most other filesystems support at least one of Linux richacls (which I don't believe is in mainline yet), NFSv4 ACLs, ZFS ACLs, or Windows ACLs, all of which allow you to specifically deny 'delete', but I don't imagine you'd be willing to give up the features of btrfs just for this.

On the other hand, since you are specifically intending this to guard against simple errors, you might be better off taking advantage of btrfs's snapshot capabilities using something like autosnap.

Answer (score 0):

I think one solution would be to just create a function in your `bashrc`, e.g.:

```bsh
sudowrapper () { 
sudo -k;sudo "$@";sudo -K; 
}

vimf() {
    echo "pass" | sudowrapper -S nvim "$1"
}
```

`sudowrapper` is required to make `sudo` forget the credentials every time `vimf` is called, otherwise it gives weird behavior.

Do this only if you want to save you from doing something wrong yourself if your goal is to prevent others from doing something bad then writing your password in `.bashrc` is a bad idea.